# I have a problem with a project I am working on involving chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, chart.js

Ok, I wrote a code which would collect user's input and then display it in any chart of their choice but on running the code, it doesn't display any chart after I have inputed my values and clicked generate chart and just refreshes the page. This is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>School Project</h1>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <a href="#" onclick="showChartsPage()">Charts</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showFormsPage()">Send Forms</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="chartsPage">
        <h2>Chart Display Page</h2>
    </div>

    <form id="dataForm">

        <div>
            <label for="labelsInput">Labels (comma-separated):</label>
            <input type="text" id="labelsInput" placeholder="Label 1, Label 2, Label 3">
        </div>

        <label for="dataInput">Enter Data: </label>
        <input type="text" id="dataInput" required>

        <label for="chartType">Select Chart Type you want:</label>
        <select id="chartType">
            <option value="bar">Bar Chart</option>
            <option value="pie">Pie Chart</option>
            <option value="radar">Radar Chart</option>
            <option value="line">Line Chart</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="generateChart()">Generate the selected chart</button>
        <div><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
    </form>

    <div id="formsPage" class="card" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Send Google Forms</h2>
        <img src="Project/download.png" alt="Picture of a Form">
        <p>Send Created Google Forms here</p>
        <button onclick="sendGoogleForm()">Send Google Form</button>
    </div>


    <script>
        function showChartsPage() {
            document.getElementById('chartsPage').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('formsPage').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function showFormsPage() {
            document.getElementById('chartsPage').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('formsPage').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function generateChart() {
            const dataInput = document.getElementById("dataInput").value;
            const labelsInput = document.getElementById('labelsInput').value;
            const dataArray = dataInput.split(",").map(Number);
            const chartType = document.getElementById('chartType').value;

            const labels = labelsInput.split(',').map(label => label.trim());
            const data = dataInput.split(',').map(value => parseFloat(value.trim()));

            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

            if (window.myChart) {
                window.myChart.destroy();
            }

            window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: chartType,
                data: {
                    labels: Array.from({
                        length: dataArray.length
                    }, (_, i) => i + 1),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'User Data',
                        data: dataArray,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
            });
        }

        function generateChart() {
            const chartType = document.getElementById('chartType').value;
            const userData = document.getElementById('userData').value.split(',').map(Number);

            // Use Chart.js to create a chart
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: chartType,
                data: {
                    labels: Array.from({
                        length: userData.length
                    }, (_, i) => i + 1),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'User Data',
                        data: userData,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

That is the code above.

I tried checking if my chart.js was correctly installed and it was. I tried different codes and still the same outcome as I just saw blank instead of a chart of my choice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two functions named generateChart() in your script, and both are trying to create a chart. The second one seems to overwrite the first one, and it might be causing the issue.

Here's a revised version of your script with the duplicate function removed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>School Project</h1>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <a href="#" onclick="showChartsPage()">Charts</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="showFormsPage()">Send Forms</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="chartsPage">
        <h2>Chart Display Page</h2>
    </div>

    <form id="dataForm">
        <div>
            <label for="labelsInput">Labels (comma-separated):</label>
            <input type="text" id="labelsInput" placeholder="Label 1, Label 2, Label 3">
        </div>

        <label for="dataInput">Enter Data: </label>
        <input type="text" id="dataInput" required>

        <label for="chartType">Select Chart Type you want:</label>
        <select id="chartType">
            <option value="bar">Bar Chart</option>
            <option value="pie">Pie Chart</option>
            <option value="radar">Radar Chart</option>
            <option value="line">Line Chart</option>
        </select>

        <button onclick="generateChart()">Generate the selected chart</button>
        <div><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
    </form>

    <div id="formsPage" class="card" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Send Google Forms</h2>
        <img src="Project/download.png" alt="Picture of a Form">
        <p>Send Created Google Forms here</p>
        <button onclick="sendGoogleForm()">Send Google Form</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function showChartsPage() {
            document.getElementById('chartsPage').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('formsPage').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function showFormsPage() {
            document.getElementById('chartsPage').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('formsPage').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function generateChart() {
            const dataInput = document.getElementById("dataInput").value;
            const labelsInput = document.getElementById('labelsInput').value;
            const dataArray = dataInput.split(",").map(Number);
            const chartType = document.getElementById('chartType').value;

            const labels = labelsInput.split(',').map(label => label.trim());
            const data = dataInput.split(',').map(value => parseFloat(value.trim()));

            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

            if (window.myChart) {
                window.myChart.destroy();
            }

            window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: chartType,
                data: {
                    labels: Array.from({
                        length: dataArray.length
                    }, (_, i) => i + 1),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'User Data',
                        data: dataArray,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work yet, I think for two reasons: 1. In most browsers, `window.myChart` is initialized to `document.getElementById('myChart')`, (as per [Named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) in HTML spec), which in OP's html is the canvas element; a safer test would be `if (window.myChart && window.myChart.destroy)` or `if (window.myChart?.destroy)` ...

Comment: ... 2. The button has the default type of submit and results in the submission of the form; one way to prevent that is to declare the button of `type="button"`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836076/16466946). | With these two changes, you'll get some output for the text input `1,2,3`, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atu7x6h8/)